# API Key in curl

Tags: php, curl

So my question is the following, using xampp for localhost, using PHP 7+ and curl, i need to make an API post call. it was given to me an API Key, that i don t know how to validate. this is the code:

```
<?php


    $curl = curl_init();

    $data_array = array(
        "amount" => '1',
        "operative"=> "AUTHORIZATION",
        "signature"=> "KKbAWfePbyt41T7inU8ulGtR",
        "customer_ext_id"=> "IDInterno",
        "additional"=> "Additional",
        "service"=>"CE4C4D1C-2A2C-4AA7-BE59-62E497AEFE16",
        "secure"=> true,
        "url_post"=> "https://demo.pagaqui.pt:5135/RegisterCard.aspxOk: ", 
        "url_ok"=> "https://carteira.pagaqui.pt/repo/ok.htmlKO: ",
        "url_ko"=> " https://carteira.pagaqui.pt/repo/nok.html ",
        "template_uuid"=> "43D8016C-D28C-4F44-899A-2195CA8DC023",
        "description"=> "Desc"
    );

    $data_array = http_build_query($data_array);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-gateway.pagaqui.pt/v1/sandbox/payment');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['content-type: application/json']);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_array);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $err = curl_error($curl);
    if($err){
        echo 'Curl Error: ' . $err;
    }
    else {
        print_r($response);
    }
<?php
```

My response in the localhost is

{"message":"Unauthorized","code":401,"details":""}

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: This will depend largely on how the API has been developed to accept API keys. You should refer to the documentation for the API in question.

Comment: Yes the API accepts Keys.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it, just needed to create a variable to the key, and after that, inside         `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Authorization: Bearer ".$Key, 'Content-Type: application/json' ));`

Thank you.